# What is the best way to show invoice details in email?

Tags: tables

I am having a problem creating e-mail design for my company. I try to create a table for invoice details and i don't know what is the best way to show info in a clear way to the user.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked in the online invoicing domain for over 15 years and from my experience users will expect an invoice to look a certain way.  I think what you have is spot on...a tabular layout with numerical columns right aligned and a total at the bottom.  A few years ago we added a toggle to switch a tabular line item layout to a card layout.  Almost nobody uses it, and those who tried it quickly switched back.